# Xgboost plottree error: Unable to parse node: 0:[petal

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I'm trying to use the plot_tree as in this [tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/visualize-gradient-boosting-decision-trees-xgboost-python/)

I'm using the iris dataset to train the model, this is the code I have:

```
from numpy import loadtxt
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from xgboost import plot_tree
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import shap



X,y = shap.datasets.iris()
y = pd.Series([v if v==1 else 0 for v in y]) 

model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X, y)
# plot single tree
plot_tree(model)
plt.show()
```

From there, I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: Unable to parse node: 0:[petal
```

I don't know where to look for that since the model does the training and prediction without issues.

I'm using version '0.20.3' of sklearn

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and it wasn't related to the graphviz installation. In my case the problem was that some of my column names of the pandas dataFrame had white space.
See also discussion on [github](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/4228#issuecomment-470715001).

When I added

```
df.rename(columns = lambda x: x.replace(' ', '_'), inplace=True)
```

to my preprocessing it solved the issue.

Comment: Yeah,  was the same thing for me. Pretty werid

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have graphviz installed. Because the plot_tree of XGboost internally uses graphviz for plotting.